# Qt multithread debug message: "ppsjy:[MyHookProc]__read web cfg: success ------ :"

Tags: qt, debugging, message

When I run a `qtconcurrent thread` test application in Qt Creator, there output a message:

```
ppsjy:[MyHookProc]__read web cfg: success ------ :
```

Is anyone knows what it means, and where it from? thanks!

Comment: Why are you worried, the test application returns `success`?

Comment: i just want to know what it means, has nothing to do with success or failed.